# How can I make this query injection-proof? (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, sql-injection

**The Gist**

I want to perform an SQL query that depends on a variable number of parameters in my GET without being vulnerable to SQL injection.

**The Parameters**

My URL can be formed like this:

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?param1=blah1,param2=blah2,param3=a,b,c
```

or like this:

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?param1=blah1,param2=blah2,param3=a,b,c,d,e,f,g
```

In other words, param3 can have a variable number of comma-delimited parameters a,b,c,etc.

**The White-list**

I check to make sure that all parameters in a,b,c,etc. are in an approved white-list before I perform the query.

```
// $valid_params is an array of pre-approved parameters.
$arr = explode(',', clean($_GET['param3']));
$params = Array();
foreach($arr as $param){
  if(in_array($param, $valid_params)){
    array_push($params, $param);
  }
}
```

**The Query**

I set up my database connection like this (with MySQL):

```
$db_connection = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_HOST};dbname={$DB_NAME}",$DB_USER,$DB_PASS);
$db_connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$db_connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

And I want to perform a query like this (except safely):

```
$comma_separated_params = implode(',',$params);
$result = $db_connection->query("SELECT {$comma_separated_params} FROM some_table");
```

**The Goal**

Does anyone know how I could do this safely and efficiently?

Comment: Nice question. You can use prepared statements to make sure it is safe. Efficient? It is already efficient right?

Comment: The whitelist already makes it pretty safe.

Comment: be very cautious about allowing an HTTP GET param to dictate what fields are selected in a query.  using a whitelist is definitely a good place to start.I'd try to define use-cases, and pass params that define which use-case is in effect.  Then use a prebuilt select list per use-case

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your concern for overhead, you could just `SELECT *` and then filter the array in PHP - if the parameter is never sent to the database then there is no room for injection.

However it's not exactly the most elegant solution. Here's how I'd do it:

```
$comma_separated_params =
  implode(
    ",",
    array_map(
      function($a) {return "`".$a."`";},
      array_intersect(
        explode(",",$_GET['param3']),
        $valid_params
      )
    )
  )
);
```

That one-line-wonder (with newlines added for clarity) will take the `$_GET['param3']` variable, split it on commas, intersect it with your valid parameters (instead of your `foreach` loop), wraps each element in backticks (see note below) and finally glues them together with commas.

See, backticks allow you to use literally any string as a field name. Usually it's to allow keywords as names, but it can also allow for column names with spaces, and so on. The only character that has meaning within the backticks are backslashes and backticks - which it is safe to assume are not present since they'd have to be in your list of `$valid_params` to get this far.

Answer (score 0):

Whitelisting is the way to go here. If you only allow things in that you've already specifically defined you should be okay. As for how efficient, this is all relative. The version you're using will perform well for relatively small lists, such as those with under 100 columns, so I wouldn't worry.

Bonus points for using PDO.

There's a chance your definition of 'allowed' columns and what's actually in the database might diverge. A more relaxed specification might be to grab the fields using `SHOW FIELDS` for the table in question and only allow those.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only allowing a specific list of predefined values to be passed in param 3, and you are comparing the input values against them, I don;t think you have any injection exposure, as you then have full control over the value that ultimately go into your `$comma_seperated_params` variable.

Answer (score 0):

This needs some work to finish, but with parameter binding it would look like this:

```
$binding = array();
$selects = array();
foreach ( $params as $value ) {
  $binding[] = ':' . $value; 
  $selects = '?';
}

$select = implode(',', $select);

$result = $db_connection->prepare("SELECT $select FROM some_table"); 
foreach ( $binding as $key => $bind ) {
  $result->bindParam($key, $bind, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}

$result->execute();
```

Comment: This appears to be the way to go, although my application timed out when I attempted to fetchAll after using your method (and your method appears to have quite a few syntax errors). I also timed out when I tried to fetch in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

[PDO::prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) will help you. This is exactly is recommended by experts. Never use `mysql_real_escape_string (string)`. Always go for prepared statements.